# How can I customize Devise to send password reset emails using PostMark mailer

Tags: devise, forgot-password, ruby-on-rails-3, postmark

I'm trying to get all of my system's email notifications under one umbrella using [PostMarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com) and utilizing the Rails gems ([postmark-rails](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails), [postmark-gem](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-gem), and [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail)). I have successfully created a mailer that handles sending receipts for purchases but I haven't been able to receive emails for forgotten passwords. My development logs show that Devise sent the message but no email is received in my inbox and the PostMark credits are not decremented.

What's the best or easiest way to have Devise's mailers send through my PostMark account?

**Snippet from config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method      = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings    = { :api_key => "VALID_API_KEY_WAS_HERE" }
config.postmark_signature                 = VALID_POSTMARK_SIGNATURE_WAS_HERE
```

**My Mailer that uses Postmark**

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  # set some sensible defaults
  default :from => MyApp::Application.config.postmark_signature

  def receipt_message(order)
    @order = order
    @billing_address = order.convert_billing_address_to_hash(order.billing_address)

    mail(:to => @order.user.email, :subject => "Your Order Receipt", :tag => 'order-receipt', :content_type => "text/html") do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

### **EDIT: SOLUTION to my question is below**

Solved it by having my `Notifier` mailer extend Devise::Mailer and specifying Devise to use my Notifier as the mailer within `config/initializers/devise.rb`

**snippet from config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
# Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
config.mailer = "Notifier"
```

**My Notifier Mailer now**

```
class Notifier < Devise::Mailer
  # set some sensible defaults
  default :from => MyApp::Application.config.postmark_signature

  # send a receipt of the Member's purchase
  def receipt_message(order)
    @order = order
    @billing_address = order.convert_billing_address_to_hash(order.billing_address)

    mail(:to => @order.user.email, :subject => "Your Order Receipt", :tag => 'order-receipt', :content_type => "text/html") do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  # send password reset instructions
  def reset_password_instructions(user)
     @resource = user
     mail(:to => @resource.email, :subject => "Reset password instructions", :tag => 'password-reset', :content_type => "text/html") do |format|
       format.html { render "devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions" }
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: fyi, you can (and should) add your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 21):

Using the latest version of Devise, the methods above didn't help me. This is my solution.

In config/application.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method   = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => "your-API-key-here" }
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.mailer = "UserMailer" # UserMailer is my mailer class
```

In app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  default from: "default@mydomain.com"

  def confirmation_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions)
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions)
  end

  # you can then put any of your own methods here
end
```

Finally, make sure you have generated custom devise views

```
rails generate devise:views
```

and move the email templates from app/views/devise/mailer/ to app/views/user_mailer/

```
mv app/views/devise/mailer/* app/views/user_mailer/
```

Comment: Needs to be updated to `def reset_password_instructions(record,token,options)`

Comment: Just in case anyone finds this, the latest version of Devise's default mailer definitions have three arguments, not one.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/66db52ce31b5d8629f5813a1d7f03a8bc17e5d52/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to specify 'tags' in postmark headers you have to do this in your mailer:

```
  # this override method is from Devise::Mailers::Helpers
  def headers_for(action)
    headers = {
      :subject        => translate(devise_mapping, action),
      :from           => mailer_sender(devise_mapping),
      :to             => resource.email,
      :template_path  => template_paths,
      :tag            => action.dasherize # specify the tag here
    }
    if resource.respond_to?(:headers_for)
      headers.merge!(resource.headers_for(action))
    end
    unless headers.key?(:reply_to)
      headers[:reply_to] = headers[:from]
    end
    headers
  end
```

Comment: I had to change this line from `:tag => action.dasherize` to `:tag => action.to_s.dasherize`.  Otherwise this seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to generate the views for devise and copy the mail templates into the right place for my mailer.  Something like this -

```
rails generate devise:views
cp app/views/devise/mailer/* app/views/notification_mailer/
```