# Rails 2.3: SMTP settings for Postmarkapp: Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, postmark

Does anybody have experience with Postmarkapp?

I have a rails 2 app (radiant cms) and try to send emails through SMTP.

This is how my smtp settings looks like:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.postmarkapp.com",
  :port           => '25',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => 'postmark-ap-key',
  :password       => 'postmark-ap-key',
  :domain => 'postmarkapp.com'
}
```

The Mailer class:

```
class RegistrationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def send_email(email, sent_at = Time.now)
    subject "Some text here"
    recipients "#{email}"
    from 'xxx@yxz.com'
    sent_on sent_at
    body :text => "Some text here"
  end

end
```

and here is the code where I call the deliver method (in a controller action):

```
mail = RegistrationMailer.create_send_email(params[:email])
RegistrationMailer.deliver(mail)
```

I got an 'Connection refused - connect(2)' error whenever I call the deliver method. Anybody can help me out what am I doing wrong? I used the exact same code on heroku with other smtp settings (for sendgrid) and it worked without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Postmark myself, but there appears to be a gem to help you send mail through their system, it's probably because you have to send through an API key.

https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails

http://rubygems.org/gems/postmark-rails

Relevant question for implementation: [How can I customize Devise to send password reset emails using PostMark mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679571/how-can-i-customize-devise-to-send-password-reset-emails-using-postmark-mailer)

Comment: And maybe the rejected connection to port 25 is a completely unrelated problem caused by a firewall or an ISP blocking on port 25.

Comment: There's also port 2525 made available by PostMark for this reason.

Comment: Lack of an API key will not result in a "connection refused" error.  It's a firewalling problem.