# Dynamic Devise Sender email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionmailer

In User model, each user belong to different domain/host. I want to set it to be different from address on the basis of user's domain. Can I set this in User model somewhere, or how can I make the senders address dynamic according to user's domain.

We set devise default sender address in `app/config/initializer/devise.rb` like

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = SOME EMAIL ADDRESS
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the mail.from per email basis

```
class UserMailer <ActionMailer::Base

def notification_email(user)
  mail(to:example@example.com, from:user.email, ...)
end
```

That will override your default settings.

I think you can change this settings in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"
   config.mailer = "UserMailer"
```

to your customized mailer.

Comment: if I call devise built-in emails sending functions for "Forgot your password" or "change your password". where I can set sender email address setting on the basis of users host ? How can the above mentioned example will help and work. can you please explain ?

Comment: i edit my answer above, check devise documentation, it should be quite easy to do.

Comment: also check this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679571/how-can-i-customize-devise-to-send-password-reset-emails-using-postmark-mailer)

Comment: Thanks Henry - it worked. infact the above mentioned link helped. Thanks again man

Answer (score 10):

I bumped into this because I wanted to pull the `from` address from I18n, but the initializer was running before I18n was setup.  This was the simplest solution for me:

```
config.mailer_sender = Proc.new { I18n.t('mailers.from') }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly why I was looking for it too.

Answer (score 2):

To use the Mailer helper functions by Devise, extend the devise mailer, and override the methods/mails that need a different dynamic sender:

```
class CustomDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    @token = token
    opts[:from] = "Dynamic Sender <dynamic@foo.com>"
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
  end
end
```

And configure it in you `devise.rb`:

```
config.mailer = "CustomDeviseMailer"
```

**Note**: If you don't need a dynamic sender, just define the sender in `devise.rb`:

```
config.mailer_sender = "Static sender <static@foo.com>"
```