# SSL error when sending PostMark mail with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postmark

I have an app running Rails 4.2.0, Devise 3.4.1 and the latest version of the postmark-rails gem.  At first sending a reset password mail seemed to work fine, but I never received the mails.

Then I changed `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` (it was false), which revealed the following error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Note that this is on my development machine.

I have implemented my mailer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679571/how-can-i-customize-devise-to-send-password-reset-emails-using-postmark-mailer), but here are the relevant bits:

IN /app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

 default from: "xxx@xxx.xxx" # <- From address replaced by x's

 def confirmation_instructions(record)
  devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions)
 end

 def reset_password_instructions(record,token,options)
  devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
 end

 def unlock_instructions(record)
  devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions)
 end

end
```

Then in development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

In /initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.mailer = 'UserMailer'
```

application.rb: ( i have both of these ENV variable available to my app)

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => ENV['POSTMARK_API_KEY'], :api_token => ENV['POSTMARK_API_TOKEN'] }
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'mail'
```

I have found many references to this SSL error, but couldn't find anything that I feel applies to this.

Please help?

**UPDATE:**
From various resources on the web, mainly [this](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) one, I suspect that the source of my problem may be that I'm using the older version of OpenSSL that ships with the current version of GIT for Windows.  My app works when deployed to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

The older version of OpenSSL may indeed be causing your problem. Postmark disabled SSLv3 on their API servers due to the POODLE vulnerability.  Because of that, make sure to use an [up-to-date OpenSSL version](https://www.openssl.org) and a [patched Ruby version](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/10/27/changing-default-settings-of-ext-openssl/) that includes a fix.